# Reference for the Brauer-Nesbitt theorem

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

In [Wikipedia's article on the Brauer-Nesbitt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer%E2%80%93Nesbitt_theorem), they state that given a group $G$ and a field $E$, two *semisimple* representations $\rho_1,\rho_2 : G\longrightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n(E)$ are isomorphic if and only if $\rho_1(g),\rho_2(g)$ have the same characteristic polynomials for all $g\in G$.

The references they provide however only seem to apply to finite groups. Does anyone have a reference for the version stated above?

In characteristic 0, this appears in Lang's *Algebra* as Corollary 3.8 (p650)

In the general case, this is treated in [Theorem 5.7 of Eggermont's masters thesis](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/EggermontMaster.pdf), but it feels sketchy to cite an unpublished masters thesis.

(EDIT: I forgot to include the stipulation that $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are semisimple)

Answer (score 9):

What you have asked for, is false. If $G$ is a unipotent group such that $\rho _1$ and $\rho _2$ both have unipotent images and have the same dimension $n$, then the characteristic polynomials are $(X-1)^n$ for both (for any element of the group $G$).

The Wikipedia article to which you have sent a link, states this only for semi-simple representations.

If the characteristic of the field is zero ( or is sufficiently large), then this condition on the char polynomials is equivalent to the traces of the two representations being the same, and that is a well known result. One can deduce it from Weddernburn's theorem on semi-simple algebras.

Comment: Of course, I apologize I forgot to include semisimple. I've also noted that the characteristic 0 version is in Lang's Algebra. I'm still looking for a good reference for the positive characteristic case.